# Why does 301 error occur when varnish and wordpress are linked?

Tags: varnish

I would like to use varnish as a reverse proxy to provide wordpress service.

However, even if you set the default.vcl setting, installing Proxy Cache Purge, and so on, you can follow the instructions
When accessing through varnish port, 301 Redirect occurs and it is connected to the backend origin server.

The same phenomenon occurs even if a new wordpress server is installed and a separate plug-in/theme is not installed.

Why is this happening and how can it be solved?

varnish default.vcl settings

> varnish default.vcl

```
vcl 4.1;

import std;

backend default {
    .host = "172.16.21.222";
    .port = "8000"; }

acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "127.0.0.1";
    "172.16.21.222";
    "::1"; }

sub vcl_recv {   
    if (req.url ~ "\?$") {
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
    }

    set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");

    set req.url = std.querysort(req.url);

    unset req.http.proxy;

    if(req.method == "PURGE") {
        if(!client.ip ~ purge) {
            return(synth(405,"PURGE not allowed for this IP address"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Purge-Method == "regex") {
            ban("obj.http.x-url ~ " + req.url + " && obj.http.x-host == " + req.http.host);
            return(synth(200, "Purged"));
        }
        ban("obj.http.x-url == " + req.url + " && obj.http.x-host == " + req.http.host);
        return(synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (
        req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "PATCH" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE"
    ) {
        return (pipe);
    }

    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "&(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "");
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "\?(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "?");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?&", "?");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        set req.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:REQUEST-METHOD";
        return(pass);
    }

    if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bmp|bz2|css|csv|doc|docx|eot|flac|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odt|ogg|ogm|opus|otf|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|ttf|txt|txz|wav|webm|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
        set req.http.X-Static-File = "true";
        unset req.http.Cookie;
        return(hash);
    }

    if (
        req.http.Cookie ~ "wordpress_(?!test_)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|wp-postpass|comment_author_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|woocommerce_cart_hash|woocommerce_items_in_cart|wp_woocommerce_session_[a-zA-Z0-9]+|wordpress_logged_in_|comment_author|PHPSESSID" ||
        req.http.Authorization ||
        req.url ~ "add_to_cart" ||
        req.url ~ "edd_action" ||
        req.url ~ "nocache" ||
        req.url ~ "^/addons" ||
        req.url ~ "^/bb-admin" ||
        req.url ~ "^/bb-login.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/bb-reset-password.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/cart" ||
        req.url ~ "^/checkout" ||
        req.url ~ "^/control.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/login" ||
        req.url ~ "^/logout" ||
        req.url ~ "^/lost-password" ||
        req.url ~ "^/my-account" ||
        req.url ~ "^/product" ||
        req.url ~ "^/register" ||
        req.url ~ "^/register.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/server-status" ||
        req.url ~ "^/signin" ||
        req.url ~ "^/signup" ||
        req.url ~ "^/stats" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wc-api" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-admin" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-comments-post.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-cron.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-login.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-activate.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-mail.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-login.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^\?add-to-cart=" ||
        req.url ~ "^\?wc-api=" ||
        req.url ~ "^/preview=" ||
        req.url ~ "^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/"
    ) {
         set req.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Logged in/Got Sessions";
         if(req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest") {
             set req.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Ajax";
         }
        return(pass);
    }

    unset req.http.Cookie;
    return(hash); }

sub vcl_hash {
    if(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    } }

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.x-url = bereq.url;
    set beresp.http.x-host = bereq.http.host;

    if (!beresp.http.Cache-Control) {
        set beresp.ttl = 1h;
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES:Forced";
    }

    if (bereq.http.X-Static-File == "true") {
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES:Forced";
        set beresp.ttl = 1d;
    }

    if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie ~ "wfvt_|wordfence_verifiedHuman") {
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;    }
    
    if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Got Cookies";
    } elseif(beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Cache-Control=private";
    }    }

sub vcl_deliver {
    if(req.http.X-Cacheable) {
        set resp.http.X-Cacheable = req.http.X-Cacheable;    
    } elseif(obj.uncacheable) {
        if(!resp.http.X-Cacheable) {
            set resp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:UNCACHEABLE";        
        }
    } elseif(!resp.http.X-Cacheable) {
        set resp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";
    }
    
    unset resp.http.x-url;
    unset resp.http.x-host;     }
```

> apache /etc/httpd/conf.d/wordpress.co.kr.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerName 172.16.21.222
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mywordpress-error-log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mywordpress-acces-log combined
        <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

> varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"

```
*   << Request  >> 7         
-   Begin          req 6 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1658301976.240571 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1658301976.240571 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqStart       172.16.39.62 4667 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: 172.16.21.222
-   ReqHeader      Connection: keep-alive
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: ko
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 172.16.39.62
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqUnset       Host: 172.16.21.222
-   ReqHeader      Host: 172.16.21.222
-   ReqURL         /
-   VCL_return     hash
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 8 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1658301976.348547 0.107975 0.107975
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     301
-   RespReason     Moved Permanently
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 20 Jul 2022 07:26:16 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Apache/2.4.37 (rocky)
-   RespHeader     X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.24
-   RespHeader     X-Redirect-By: WordPress
-   RespHeader     Location: http://172.16.21.222:8000/
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 0
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   RespHeader     x-url: /
-   RespHeader     x-host: 172.16.21.222
-   RespHeader     X-Cacheable: YES:Forced
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 7
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespUnset      x-url: /
-   RespUnset      x-host: 172.16.21.222
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1658301976.348631 0.108059 0.000084
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1658301976.348669 0.108098 0.000038
-   ReqAcct        416 0 416 354 0 354
-   End            
**  << BeReq    >> 8         
--  Begin          bereq 7 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1658301976.240807 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
--  BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
--  BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Language: ko
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 172.16.39.62
--  BereqHeader    Host: 172.16.21.222
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 8
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  BackendOpen    30 boot.default 172.16.21.222 8000 172.16.21.222 11024
--  BackendStart   172.16.21.222 8000
--  Timestamp      Bereq: 1658301976.241097 0.000290 0.000290
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1658301976.348336 0.107528 0.107239
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   301
--  BerespReason   Moved Permanently
--  BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 20 Jul 2022 07:26:16 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Server: Apache/2.4.37 (rocky)
--  BerespHeader   X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.24
--  BerespHeader   X-Redirect-By: WordPress
--  BerespHeader   Location: http://172.16.21.222:8000/
--  BerespHeader   Content-Length: 0
--  BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
--  TTL            RFC 120 10 0 1658301976 1658301976 1658301976 0 0 cacheable
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
--  BerespHeader   x-url: /
--  BerespHeader   x-host: 172.16.21.222
--  TTL            VCL 3600 10 0 1658301976 cacheable
--  BerespHeader   X-Cacheable: YES:Forced
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Storage        malloc s0
--  Fetch_Body     0 none -
--  BackendReuse   30 boot.default
--  Timestamp      BerespBody: 1658301976.348518 0.107711 0.000182
--  Length         0
--  BereqAcct      428 0 428 251 0 251
--  End
```

Comment: Please add the full output of `sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"` to your question. This will clarify what is going on at the time of the 301 redirection. Please ensure that the cache is empty before attempting to trigger the redirect. FYI: I'm also assuming the problem appears on the homepage, hence the `ReqUrl eq '/'` filter.

Comment: thx, I added varnishlog according to your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing is related to a `Host` header mismatch.

Your VSL log shows that you're sending the following `Host` header:

```
-   ReqHeader      Host: 172.16.21.222:6081
```

This is the result of calling `http://172.16.21.222:6081`. However, you're WordPress setup doesn't recognize that host and redirects to the host it knows, which is `172.16.21.222:8000`.

You can see that it redirects to this host in the following log line:

```
-   RespHeader     Location: http://172.16.21.222:8000/
```

You shouldn't be using port numbers in your `Host` header. I would advise you to change the default listening port of `varnishd` from `6081` to `80`.

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/installing-varnish-ubuntu/#4-configure-varnish for more information on how to change the listening port via systemd.

Please also ensure that port `8080` is not included in the WordPress base URL. Just use the IP address or a domain name instead.

For the time being you could bypass the port mismatch by overriding your `Host` header. Here's an example using `cUrl`:

```
curl -H"Host: 172.16.21.222:8000" -I http://172.16.21.222:6081
```

This command will override the host to `172.16.21.222:8000` while still accessing Varnish over `172.16.21.222:6081`.

If this works, change the `varnishd` port to `80` and updated the WordPress base URL to not include the port.

Comment: As you said, I changed the port of varnish to 80 and ran it, but I am still receiving 301 responses.

Even if I call using the curl I told you, I still get 301 responses.

Do you have any additional comments?

Comment: The logs don't reflect these changes. Please make sure you have up-to-date logs that represent the most recent setup. This includes potential port changes. Please also ensure that WordPress has a base URL that doesn't include ports.

Comment: After changing the varnish port to 80, I put the log for the request back in the body.
However, I don't know what it means to check if there is a URL that doesn't include port in wordpress.

Comment: I'm under the impression that you set up WordPress with `http://172.16.21.222:8000/` as the base URL. Unless the URL matches the base URL, a redirection takes place. Please read https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/ on how to change the site URL.